# How much time Admob need to index app from Google Play?

Tags: android, admob

How much time need admob to index application from Google Play?

I want to connect my admob account with my app what I uploaded yesterday to Google Play.

However, admob shows "application not found" error.

Even I search for my app, it returns  only my 2 old turned off application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it took some days (2~4)...
You will be able to find your app soon.

Even then, this does not impact your earnings since I believe your adUnit-ID is enough for admob.

Comment: Thanks for reply. :)